# How to construct an elliptic curve with complex multiplication and class number not 1?

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

There is a theorem that guarantees that when the j invariant of the elliptic curve E is an algebraic integer, the elliptic curve E has a complex multiplication.

But how to construct an elliptic curve corresponding to the class number **greater than 1** ?
Can you give some examples of using computer algebra systems to construct elliptic curves, such as Magma, PARI/GP, SageMath?

\begin{align*}
j(\sqrt{-10}\>\!)
&=6^3 (65 + 27\sqrt{5}\>\!)^3\\
\color{black}{j(\sqrt{-14}\>\!)}
&\color{black}{=2^3\Big(323+228 \sqrt{2}+(59+43\sqrt{2}) \sqrt{\small{7+14\sqrt{2}}\,}\,\Big)^3}\\
j\Big({\small\frac{1+\sqrt{-15}}{2}}\Big)&=-3^3\Big({\small\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}\Big)^2(5+4\sqrt{5}\>\!)^3\\
j(\sqrt{-23}\>\!)
&=\Big(\frac{23035}{3}+\frac{5(18279-1075 \sqrt{69}\>\!)\sqrt[3]{{\small108+12\sqrt{69}}}}{36}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad+\frac{5(18279+1075 \sqrt{69}\>\!) \sqrt[3]{{\small108-12\sqrt{69}}\,}}{36}\Big)^3\\
\end{align*}

Ref:
https://alexjbest.github.io/talks/singular-moduli/slides_h.pdf

Comment: I may be very wrong, because I don't know this stuff. But I would have thought that this is achieved by the construction $E=\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is an ideal of the corresponding ring of integers. To get what you look for it may be necessary to pick $\Lambda$ to correspond to a non-principal ideal?

Comment: Have you tried searching on LMFDB? For example, https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/2.2.5.1/81.1/a/1